android searchView background when cursor is focused and moving hides the text behind a white box
im using a SearchView in my android activity.
the SearchView is defined in the activity menu.xml like so:
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_48dp_action"
        android:title="@string/Search"
        android:visible="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:submitBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />

in the code its used like this:
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
SearchView filterPartsSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
filterPartsSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
filterPartsSearchView.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.transparent, null));

this is how it looks when i click the text and start moving it around:

how can i remove that white box?
i tried setting the color as transparent in menu.xml and in the activity

Seems that i found a solution.
i edited my toolbar style from this
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/white</item>
    </style>

to this
    <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<!--        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/white</item>-->
    </style>

and it worked.
not sure if anything else will be affected by removing the popupBackground property but for now its enough

use code like this
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView filterPartsSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        if (searchManager != null) {
            filterPartsSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        }

       filterPartsSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        filterPartsSearchView.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), android.R.color.transparent, null));
 
        View searchPlate = filterPartsSearchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
        if (searchPlate != null) {
            searchPlate.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

This is Ref Image of selected text

2nd image Ref when cursor pressed and hold for highlight text while move cursor around text


Thanks for your answer, sadly it did not work when i tried it, the view: SearchPlate was not null and the code is ok but i still have the same white box effect
